# Is there some way to specify "where" dynamically on a map?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

Lets consider the following simplified mapping:

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"  assembly="xxx" namespace="yyy">
  <class name="Customer" table="Customers">
    <id name="Id" column="customerID" type="Int64">
      <generator class="native"/>
    </id>

    <!-- LOOK AT THE WHERE BELOW .-->
    <map where="codeType='BO'" name="Conversions" table="CustomersCodes" >
      <key column="customerID"></key>
      <index   column="codeType" type="AnsiString"/>
      <element column="code" type="AnsiString"/>
    </map>

  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

I would like to dinamycally specify the where ( that is sticked in the mapping in the sample ) in code, is it possible ?

As a viable alternative, is it possible to fetch just a key of the map with QueryOver or LinqToNH ? I did try with link to NH but it complain that the map does not contain an entity ( true, since  it is a map of elements, that is perfectly valid in NH and useful to optimize the speed in many cases  )

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps NHibernate Filters could help you here [Contextual data using NHibernate filters](http://nhforge.org/wikis/howtonh/contextual-data-using-nhibernate-filters.aspx)

Comment: +1 because it probably works, but looking for something I can use without interceptors...